# CSS Button with different shape before and after

Tags: css, pseudo-class

[image: Button example]

I tried to code the example above, but I can't still don't get it. It works with a certain length, but when the length changes (because of the content inside) it breaks and I have to manually configure the padding-bottom.

Here an example:

[image]

And here's my code:

```
.tjbtn, .tjbtn--orange, .tjbtn--green {
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-position: center center;
    padding: 1em;
    line-height: 3em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    background-image: url("http://tj.cadman.ws/button_bg_orange.svg");
}
```

Is there any possibility to code this without an attached background-image and make this fluid regardless to the width?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What element are you using this on? Have you tried to `display:inline-block` ? Seems like a display:inline issue to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give  `display: inline-block;` and change to `background-size: 100%;` will work for you.

```
.tjbtn, .tjbtn--orange, .tjbtn--green {
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: center center;
    padding: 1em;
    line-height: 3em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    background-image: url("http://tj.cadman.ws/button_bg_orange.svg");
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ob0nmytt/)**

Comment: I think with this the problem is that the background-image gets so large when there is a lot of text that the whole button looks just like it has just a background-color (it looks like a square).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This works yes, but I've coded another solution today (needed 1 hour just for this).

I'll post it later here :)